# How to make Excel ignore quotes when reading CSV files?

Tags: excel, csv

My data is like `a, b", c, d", e`.
Excel will ignore the commas within the quotes.
How can I make Excel not do that and just read quotes as normal characters?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the CSV using Data, Get Data, From Text. As you progress though the Import Wizard, change the Text Qualifier to *none*.